# Convert string BigInteger with base 16 in c#

Tags: java, c#

I'm in the process of rewriting a Java library into C#.NET. I'm facing a problem from the code below, how do I write this in C#?

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("728faf34b64cd55c8d1d500268026ffb", 16);
System.out.println(bi);
```

Comment: When facing an issue in c# never underestimate the power of [F1] documentation, double click [your class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) and loook for the method list or code exemple. 
Most of the time you will find what [you need](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BigInteger.Parse` with a style of `NumberStyles.HexNumber`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Numerics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var number = BigInteger.Parse("728faf34b64cd55c8d1d500268026ffb", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
152278043568215137367088803326132908027
```